# JPA 2 @JoinTable with keygeneration

Tags: jpa, persistence, join

Is there a way in JPA 2 to use a @JoinTable to generate a UUID key for the id of the row? I do not want to create new entity for this table (even if that would solve the problem) and I do not want to create it from the DB.

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="Exams_Questions", schema="relation",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="examId", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="questionId", referencedColumnName = "id"))   
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

db table

```
CREATE TABLE [relation].[Exams_Questions](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [examId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [questionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
```

Comment: The question being asked is hard to understand due to grammatical problems.

Comment: Not sure if you are still around, but what solution did you finally go with? I am trying to do the same thing, no reason to make the Join Table as an @Entity when there is only 3 actual fields being the table's ID, and the two ids from the 2 tables that are being joined together by the join table.

Comment: Cant remember to be honest, But the answer given seems like the best way forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the question is, but let me try a response.

For your first sentence alone, I would say "Yes" and "Possibly":

1. You'll need a separate `@Entity class` for the `Question`, and in that class you'd specify the mapping for `id`.
2. There is no way using spec JPA to specify auto-generation of a UUID value for a column.  There are ways using [OpenJPA](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/openjpa/openjpa-persistence-jdbc/2.0.0/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.0.0-test-sources.jar!/org/apache/openjpa/persistence/generationtype/GeneratedValues.java?format=ok) and [Hibernate](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/10/10/80priamary-key-generation-strategies-in-hibernate/).  [EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomSequencing) will allow you to create a custom generator for this purpose, and their example is, in fact, for a UUID.

If you'd like to *expose* properties of the join-table OR otherwise have JPA *manage* them (i.e. the `id` on the `Exams_Questions` table), then see [this external link](http://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/) ([found on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587556/1448212)).  You'll end up with @OneToMany relations from Exam/Question entities to the join table, and @ManyToOne relations from the join table to Exam/Question entities.

Exposing the  join table as an entity will let you manage a separate key (uuid).  If you don't *need* the uuid primary key, then don't do this - it's not necessary to solve the problem, as the examId/questionId combination is unique.

Comment: Note EclipseLink 2.4 support UUID using @UuidGenerator